# Criar uma pasta em php em um repositorio especifico

Tags: php

Eu crio uma pasta pra cada usuário, porem esta criando onde esta meu arquivo php, quero criar em uma pasta dentro desse repositório onde esta o arquivo, mas não esta indo, é simples mas sou novato.

```
$parts = explode('/', $dir);
        $file = 'dados.json';
        $dir = $data;
        foreach($parts as $part)
            if(!is_dir($dir .= "/$part")) mkdir($dir);
        file_put_contents("$dir/$file", $json);
```

Tentei isso:

```
$parts = explode('/', $dir);
        $file = 'dados.json';
        $dir = $data;
        $past = 'Users'
        foreach($parts as $part)
            if(!is_dir($dir .= "/$part")) mkdir($dir);
        file_put_contents("$past/$dir/$file", $json);
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Resposta:

```
                   $parts = explode('Users/', $dir);
                    $file = 'dados.json';
                    $dir = $data;
                    foreach($parts as $part)
                    if(!is_dir($dir .= "/$part")) mkdir("Users/$dir");
                        file_put_contents("Users/$dir/$file", $json);
```

Answer (score -1):

se o código está funcionando e apenas criando a pasta no lugar errado, tente isso:

```
               $parts = explode('Users/', $dir);
                $file = 'dados.json';
                $dir = $data;
                foreach($parts as $part)
                if(!is_dir($dir .= "/$part")) mkdir("C:\Users\$dir");
                    file_put_contents("C:\Users\$dir\$file", $json);
```

onde "C:\Users\" seria o caminho completo de onde deseja criar a pasta